When deploying ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app to Azure with github repo, I get a build error
Build and run fine in my local machine.
I have two projects in the solution, TicketsApp and for Report Project that contains SSRS:


Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Tried re-deploying and run dotnet clean and rebuilding nothing works and there is no such file in .NET directory as Reporting Services I have no idea what package to install or what!

Try to find your .csproj file and add <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests> like below.
<PropertyGroup> 
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests> 
</PropertyGroup>

